# In an XML schema, is there a way to validate that a name of an element is the value of another element

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I am rather new to XML/xsd and I want to write an XML schema for XML files that I am using in my university project. This is my issue:
I have these two elements ´a´ and ´c´. I want to make sure, that the name of each element in ´c´ is the text of an element ´b´ in ´a´.

```
<a>
    <b>aa</b>
    <b>bb</b>
    <b>cc</b>
    ...
</a>
<c>
    <aa>.....</aa>
    <bb>.....</bb>
    <cc>.....</cc>
    ...
</c>
```

Is there any way to do this, or do I have to list all the names manually like this?:

```
<xs:complexType name="c">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="aa" .../>
        <xs:element name="bb" .../>
        <xs:element name="cc" .../>
        ...
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

I know that I can use assert to check whether an element exists, but I do not know if I can check that using the value of another element as the name, and I do not know if I can do this for each element ´b´, where the count of ´b´ is arbitrary.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can't be done readily in XSD 1.0. In XSD 1.1 you can write an assertion (on the common ancestor of the elements you have shown):

```
<xs:assert test="every $n in c/* satisfies name($n) = a/b"/>
```

Comment: Ah, that is really nice, thank you so much! I assume "name($n) = a/b" is true, if there is at least one element ´b´ that has name($n) as a text?

Comment: *This can't be done readily in XSD 1.0.*   Why *readily*?  Have a trick with `xs:key` in mind?

Comment: If I were constrained to use XSD 1.0, I would use the workaround of transforming before validation, e.g. by changing `<aa>` to `<element name="aa">`. An underused technique. It can even be done on-the-fly in a SAX filter placed between the XML parser and the schema validator.